# How to query automatically in Django?

Tags: python, django, view, model, web-deployment

I can retrieve data by explicitly giving the 'Id' but I want to retrieve it automatically the top 3 'Id' data. How can I do that. please check my code below and help me out

## this is models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

## this is admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','title')
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

## this is views.py

```
def index(request):
    post3 = get_object_or_404(Post, id=3)
    post2 = get_object_or_404(Post, id=2)
    post1 = get_object_or_404(Post, id=1)
    context = {
        "post3": post3,
        "post2": post2,
        "post1": post1,
    }
    return render(request, 'contents/index.html', context)
```

as you can see in the above am giving the id number and it works fine but I want it to retrieve the top id automatically

## this is my remplate

```
<h3>{{post3.title}}</h3>
<h3>{{post2.title}}</h3>
<h3>{{post1.title}}</h3>
```

Comment: `Post.objects.order_by('-id')[:3]`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use slice on queryset (it will automatically add LIMIT to the SQL query) or take objects specified by index:

```
posts = Post.objects.all()[:3]  # 3 first objects
posts = Post.objects.order_by("-id")[:3]  # 3 last objects
post = Post.objects.last()  # last object
post = Post.objects.order_by("-id")[0]  # also last object, but it's better to use `last` in such case
post = Post.objects.order_by("-id")[1]  # pre-last object
```

Pass it to the context:

```
context = {"posts": posts}
```

And then you can process this queryset in template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for ur response so this "posts = Post.objects.order_by("-id")[:3]" will give me the last 3 objects but what can I do if I specifically want just one object which is the 2nd last object

Comment: In such case you can use:
`post = Post.objects.order_by("-id")[1]` (so it's not last created object, but the one previous this one)

Comment: I tried running the code "Post.objects.order_by("-id")[:0]" this will give me 404, "Post.objects.order_by("-id")[:1]" this gives me the last object and when I try "Post.objects.order_by("-id")[:2]" it gives me both the last and second last objects but what I want is only the second last

Comment: it's because you're using `:`, which is making slice. If you want to receive only one object, then use just `[1]` without `:`

Comment: thank you very much. I was totally confused since last week. u help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

you should query in **views** for instance `posts = Post.objects.all()[0:3]` and then in **template** use for loop

```
{% for post in posts %}
   {{ post.title }}
```

If you want to create DetailView you can pass post.id via template and add it as parameter in view, then `Post = get_object_or_404(id=post_id)`